Geographic distribution of Bitcoin users
I haven't found recent question about this subject. I wanted to know if there was a site or a database with the geographic distribution of Bitcoin users freely available ? I know that there are several limitations but I've seen research papers (and Chainalysis) estimating this. The main goal is possibly to have time series of volume of transactions per country.


Geographic distribution of Bitcoin users

No one can know the geographic distribution of Bitcoin users with any certainty.
For example, a user in France might access a Bitcoin node in the USA. The node might not know the location of the user. In addition, the user might use a VPN that disguises their location.
As another example, how would anyone collect the location of a Bitcoin user who moved their money into a paper wallet and relocated?
The locations of nodes is not a reliable indication of the locations of users.


The main goal is possibly to have time series of volume of transactions per country.

I doubt this is straightforward. If a user in France and a user in Japan provide a 2 of 3 multi-signature input to a transaction that pays someone in Mexico, what countries' volumes does that transaction contribute towards?
Given my first point, this is moot anyway.

Related : How much bitcoin in Canada?.

This isn't exactly what you want but Bitnodes has a breakdown of reachable full nodes by geography. As RedGrittyBrick discusses this breakdown doesn't necessarily give an accurate indication of volume of transactions by geography and indeed Bitcoin Core developers have in the past (and continue to) made it as hard as possible for a network observer to assess from which full node a particular transaction was initially broadcast from.
